# gps coordinates of train routes

Tags: geospatial, usa, openstreetmap

I have a project wherein having train route information would be useful. Like if I could get GPS coordinates that form the routes themselves I could do maps like https://www.amtrak.com/track-your-train.html using the [Simple Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) API on Google Maps.

Is that stuff publicly available? I'm most specifically interested in this for Texas railroads: https://ftp.txdot.gov/pub/txdot-info/tpp/maps/2016-railroad.pdf

Comment: the PDF you link has some vector mapping underneath. I'm thinking it's possible to extract the geodata, see, for example, here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/169472/112869 (if that's the case, it may be a better question for the GIS site)

Comment: Did you [contact](https://www.txdot.gov/content/txdot-redesign/en/contactUsLandingPage/askAGeneralQuestion.html) the Tx DOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both https://data-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/usdot::north-american-rail-network-lines and https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/2a9677db741d4a78bd221586fe9a61f5_0/data appear to have this data as KMLs, Shapefiles, etc

https://www.fla-etat.org/est/metadata/rails_abandoned.htm explains the various fields.

https://gis-txdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/90f8c6d733274c26b9c8ea25e41fff62_0 has this data for Texas, specifically.